# Creating multiple files using batch files

Tags: batch-file

Hi Can anyone help me out in this problem.

I need to create multiple file?? i give with any example. In some folder, say Folder Records.
"Record" folder contain 1 file by name "example2tought1023.au"  . i need to generate same file contains, multiple time just by increasing the numbers.

i should get result like this example2tought1023.au example3tought1024.au example4tought1025.au example5tought1026.au

This is what I currently have:

```
SET count=9

SET filename_1=example
SET filename_2=thought

SET extension=.au

SET start_1=2
SET start_2=1023

SET source=%filename_1%%start_1%%filename_2%%start_2%%extension%

FOR /L %%i IN (1, 1, %count%) DO (
  REM These two lines do not work!
  SET /a n=%start_1%+%%i
  SET /a number_2=%start_2% + %%i

  SET destination=%filename_1%%number_1%%filename_2%%number_2%%extension%

  ECHO %destination%
  REM COPY %source% %destination%
)

PAUSE
```

but the lines in the `FOR /L` loop do not work

Comment: @user3163527 Welcome to SO! It's a common technique in batch to simply `ECHO` the required changes so that OP can verify that the commands are correct. In this case, the `COPY` command is `REM`med out. All you need do is to remove the `REM` from the `COPY` line, once you've verified that the results are correctly echoed. This makes sure that nothing actually *happens* (as observed) until it has been verified. You'll find your question has be marked 'not an answer'. This is normal. We're aware that you haven't enough rep(utation) to respond in comments.

Answer (score 2):

You have mis-identified which lines are not working :-)

The problem you are having relates to when variables are expanded. Normal expansion using percents occurs when the line is parsed, and your entire FOR statement, including the parenthesised DO clause, is parsed in one go. So the following line

```
SET destination=%filename_1%%number_1%%filename_2%%number_2%%extension%
```

is seeing the values of %number_1% and %number_2% that existed *before* the loop was executed. Obviously not what you want. The solution is simple - you need to use delayed expansion (the value at run time instead of parse time). You do that by 1st enabling delayed expansion using `setlocal enableDelayedExpansion`, and then use `!number_1!` instead of `%number_1%`.

You are not consistent with your variable names (n vs number_1).

I think you want to count from 0 to count-1 instead of from 1 to count.

You do not have to explictly expand the variable when using a variable in a SET /A expression. You can simply use the variable name without percents or exclamations. But this only works with the SET /A command.

You can also perform multiple computations and assignments with a single SET /A command by using a comma between each assignment.

```
@echo off
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion

REM counts from 0 to count, so 8 = 9 copies
set count=8

set filename_1=example
set filename_2=thought

set extension=.au

set start_1=2
set start_2=1023

set source=%filename_1%%start_1%%filename_2%%start_2%%extension%

for /L %%i in (0, 1, %count%) do (
  set /a "number_1=start_1+%%i, number_2=start_2+%%i"
  set destination=%filename_1%!number_1!%filename_2%!number_2!%extension%
  echo !destination!
  REM copy %source% !destination!
)

pause
```

Comment: looking at his example of desired output, it seems he really just wants to add 1 each time, not %%i (which would end up adding 1,2,3,4,5....)

Comment: @SeanCheshire - Look carefully - I am adding %%i to the START value and assigning it to a NUMBER variable, so it gives the correct values. I did it this way because that is how the OP structured the original code. The version before my edit had it more in line with what you are describing, simply incrementing a value. But both methods give the same result.

Comment: ah- ok. I am *way* more used to incrementing, rather than adding on to a base number :D